# C#--How do I use a Null Coalescing operator to allow use of an extension method that won't accept null parameters?

Tags: c#, linq, operators, nullable

I have a property that is part of a select clause in a LINQ statement.  It is a due date that needs to be converted to UTC.

Unfortunately, this particular property is a nullable datetime object, so I am being prevented from using the `.ToUniversalTime()` extension.

Shouldn't I be allowed to use the null coalescing operator to handle this?  I am attempting to do so, but the compiler isn't happy about it:

```
item.DueDate ?? null ?? item.DueDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o")
```

Am I missing something simple here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
item.DueDate == null ? null : item.DueDate.Value.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `GetValueOrDefault` method on `Nullable<T>`, much cleaner than trinary or null coalesce:

```
item.DueDate.GetValueOrDefault(yourDefaultHere).ToUniversalTime();
```

Comment: This is promising, but everything I am putting in the method signature of `GetValueOrDefault` is failing.  I would have thought that simply putting `null` would work, but it's looking for a nullable datetime object.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the null coalescing operator to handle these scenarios where a method is called on an nullable object.

Try the following.

```
item.DueDate != null ? item.DueDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o") : null;
```